# How to get multiple dynamic drop-down option values in one single list in Angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, dropdown

I am creating a dynamic multiple dropdown in angualar 8. I am receiving list of list from backend and I am running through the list of list to generate multiple dynamic dropdown. Now I need to send selected option values from all the dropdown to backend again in Angular 8. I am unable to send all the value.

I am getting list in this format from which I am looping through to generate dynamic drop-down

cat_dropdown = [['A','B','C'],['1','2','3']]

Based on above list my html code generate two drop-downs one with options A,B,C and another with 1,2,3.

My HTML Code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="segmentSelection()" #ff="ngForm">
   <div id="userSelection" ngModelGroup="userData" #userData="ngModelGroup">
   <div *ngFor="let first of cat_dropdown">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Choose Segment Key</mat-label>
                <mat-select id="selectme" name="segmentKey">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let segment of first" [value]="segment">
                    {{segment}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
</form>
```

My component.ts code:

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class myComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild("ff", { static: true }) segmentData: NgForm;

 plotselection = {
    segmentKey: []

  }

segmentSelection(){

  this.plotselection.segmentKey = this.segmentData.value.userData.segmentKey;

  fetch("http://localhost:5000/data-decomposition", {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },body: JSON.stringify({
       segmentKey: this.segmentData.value.userData.segmentKey,

     })
   }).then(res => res.json()).then(myjson => {
             console.log(myjson)
     })
}
```

Now in my .ts component I have a dictionary name "plotselection" where I have key name 'segmentKey' which I defined as empty list.

As I have 2 dropdown in frontend so thought that i will receive two values from frontend and I will send those as a list to backend. When I select option from both the dropdowns for example from 1st dropdown I choose 'B' and from 2nd '3' and submit my selection, then when I console log the response I could only see the value '3' in my list not 'B' and '3' together. How can I have both the value to the list.

Thank you, and looking for your suggestion...

Comment: Hey man, what exactly are you trying to achieve? It's a little difficult to follow, can you simply your explanation?

Comment: i want to achieve a list with all the selected options values from 2 list generated above dynamically

Comment: Ok cool. Just flatten the array and read the list.

Comment: after selecting options from 2 dropdowns when I am console.log the list or array, I am only getting the value of 2nd dropdown value, not both 1st, 2nd dropdown values...I think its overriding the previous value and just displaying the last value enter....

Comment: I see, in that case you'll need to make sure (check) it's not overriding.

Answer (score 0):

For my easiness I have used `Select` control instead of `mat-select` control.
In the form I have given specific name by appending the index to control while looping.

***Html***

```
<div *ngFor="let first of cat_dropdown; let num = index">
             <div> 
                <Label>Choose Segment Key</Label>
                <Select   id="selectme{{num}}" [value]="segment" name="segmentKey{{num}}" (change)="ChangeCall($event.target)">
                  <option *ngFor="let segment of first"  >
                    {{segment}}
                  </option>
                </Select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So that there are two controls with respective selected values.

There is also alternate solution is use to Change event on the Select Control.